# How to add selector in jQuery that selects one nested class and DOES NOT select the rest, which are not in the same nest

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I want to select a class to animate in jQuery which is triggered when you hover (mouseover) a 'block' class. There are three copies of these blocks on the page. How do I only select one to animate instead of all of them simultaneously?
I did it by element ID before, it worked, but it was too tedious copying the code 6 times. (mouseover & mouseout). I changed it to add find() but it just stopped working all together.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".block", this).mouseover(function() {

    $(this) find(".display-none").animate({
      opacity: "1"
    }, 300);
    $(this).find(".movable-block").animate({
      top: "2%",
      paddingBottom: "10%"
    }, 300);
    $(this).find(".images-folder").animate({
      height: "120px"
    }, 300);

  });

  $(".block", this).mouseout(function() {

    $(this) find(".display-none").animate({
      opacity: "0"
    }, 300);
    $(this).find(".movable-block").animate({
      top: "15%",
      paddingBottom: "0"
    }, 300);
    $(this).find(".images-folder").animate({
      height: "200px"
    }, 300);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row block-cols">
    <div class="col-md-4 block" id="first-block">
      <div class="movable-block" id="movable1">
        <img class="images-folder middle-out" id="first-image" src="images/Dunce.png">
        <h3 class="middle-out" id="first-title"> <strong> Title Bar </strong> One </h3>
      </div>
      <p class="display-none" id="first-nonex">This is the paragraph that is opaque right now but will appear over hover</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 block" id="smallerblock1">
      <div class="movable-block" id="movable2">
        <img class="images-folder middle-out" id="second-image" src="images/team.png">
        <h3 class="middle-out" id="second-title"> <strong> Title Bar </strong> Two</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="display-none" id="second-nonex">This is the paragraph that is opaque right now but will appear over hover</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 block" id="smallerblock2">
      <div class="movable-block" id="movable3">
        <img class="images-folder middle-out" id="third-image" src="images/fast.png">
        <h3 class="middle-out" id="third-title"> <strong> Title Bar </strong> Two</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="display-none" id="third-nonex">This is the paragraph that is opaque right now but will appear over hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some HTML code: it is a mess as there are a bunch of classes and IDs everywhere but it was the aftermath of me trying to fix it :)

Comment: Add some HTML code

Comment: done! mind the excessive amount of classes, trying to find a way to do this

Comment: what is the jquery version

Comment: @zan The version is 1.12.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your code

Missing dot here, before find function

```
$(this)find(".display-none").animate({opacity: "1"},300);
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/f8ypa/1199/

Comment: Can't up vote as I don't have the rep :/ but I accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS

```
.display-none{
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.5s ease;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block").on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).find(".display-none").css('opacity','1');
  });
  $(".block").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find(".display-none").css('opacity','0');
  });
});
```